# How to get rid of the unicode 'u' from output ? Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unicode, boto

The following code looks for 0.0.0.0/0 in sec group and prints on slack.

````
def getTag(connection, instanceId):
    reservations=connection.get_all_instances(filters={'instance_id':instanceId})
    for res in reservations:
      for instance in res.instances:
        if instance.state == "running":
           return instance.tags['Name'],instance.private_ip_address,instance.region
        else:
           return None

#regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
#regions = ['us-west-2','eu-central-1','ap-southeast-1']  ##Prod VPC
regions = ['us-west-2']
data = []
header = ["Port","Open For","Security group","Instance Details"]

for region in regions:
    connection=ec2.connect_to_region(region)
    sg = connection.get_all_security_groups()
    try:
        for securityGroup in sg:
           for rule in securityGroup.rules:
               if '0.0.0.0/0' in str(rule.grants):
                  for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                      instanceId=str(instanceid)
                     # print instanceId
                      tag = getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1])
                      if tag is not None:
                        # print tab              
                         tab =[str(rule.to_port),"0.0.0.0/0",str(securityGroup.name),str(getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1]))]
                         data.append(tab)
    except Exception,e:
        pass

print tabulate(data, headers=header, tablefmt='simple')
cool_stuff = tabulate(data, headers=header, tablefmt='simple')
slack.chat.post_message('#scanbot','```'+cool_stuff+'```',username='AWS_security_group_scanner')
````

The problem is , this prints :

```
 Port  Open For    Security group                     Instance Details
------  ----------  ---------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1433  0.0.0.0/0   default                            (u'ABCcorp', u'10.17.9.22', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   pdx01-ms-dev-elbs                  (u'dev-lb05', u'10.17.5.249', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   pdx01-ms-dev-elbs                  (u'dev-sdl-lb02', u'10.17.5.63', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   pdx01-ms-dev-elbs                  (u'lbCasio', u'10.17.5.11', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   pdx01-ms-dev-elbs                  (u'lb01', u'10.17.4.196', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   pdx01-ms-dev-elbs                  (u'lb01', u'10.17.5.133', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
    80  0.0.0.0/0   pdx01-ms-dev-elbs                  (u'gehc-lb01', u'10.17.5.222', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
   443  0.0.0.0/0   pdx01-ms-dev-elbs                  (u'lb05', u'10.17.5.249', RegionInfo:us-west-2)
```

I want to get rid of the  'u' since they are messing with the slack stuff. can someone help me ?

Comment: Try to print the string instead of a tuple

Comment: Use `print str(something)`, instead of `print something`

Comment: As written in the linked question, why not just use Python 3?

Comment: most of my server run on default python 2.7

Comment: @hyst329 and there will be too many syntax changes for that

Comment: @Nishant Singh And also, `except Exception, e` is considered bad practice even in 2.7 (and it's completely wrong in 3). Write `except Exception as e`.

Comment: @hyst329 well yes correct, but what about 

print tabulate(data, headers=header, tablefmt='simple')
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Nishant Singh Simply put the expression to parentheses: print(tabulate(...)). It's not that hard, however it's one of the most major incompatibilities between 2 and 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110334/discussion-between-nishant-singh-and-hyst329).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
tab  = [str(rule.to_port), "0.0.0.0/0", str(securityGroup.name), str(getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1]))]
```

to

```
tab  = [str(rule.to_port), "0.0.0.0/0", str(securityGroup.name), tuple(list(i.encode('UTF8') for i in getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1])[0:2] ) + [getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1])[2]] )]
```

Comment: this works fine, but the last `RegionInfo` is missing

Comment: i thought you would not want that(no need to change) to be converted to any type.

Comment: i mean i just needed to get rid of `u` , ur code seems fine, but the `RegionInfo` is gone its not being printed in the output.. rest is okay..

Comment: @Nishant. I have made the changes to include the missing item.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this works

```
import unicodedata
for region in regions:
    connection=ec2.connect_to_region(region)
    sg = connection.get_all_security_groups()
    try:
        for securityGroup in sg:
           for rule in securityGroup.rules:
               if '0.0.0.0/0' in str(rule.grants):
                  for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                      instanceId=str(instanceid)
                     # print instanceId
                      tag = getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1])
                      if tag is not None:
                        # print tab              
                         tab =[str(rule.to_port),"0.0.0.0/0",str(securityGroup.name),unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1])).encode('ascii','ignore')]
                         data.append(tab)
    except Exception,e:
        pass
```

Comment: This isn't working as expected.,, just breaks out of the first loop.. no data nothing